# How to troubleshoot a dispatch_group_leave crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I know that `dispatch_group_leave` calls need to be balanced with `dispatch_group_enter`.
Here is the block of code where my crash is happening (randomly, not always)

```
            dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
            dispatch_group_enter(group);
            [self getVibrationHistorySuccess:^(NSArray<VibrationPointDTO *> *vibrationPoints) {
                self.vibrationPoints = vibrationPoints;
                dispatch_group_leave(group);
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                dispatch_group_leave(group);
            }];

            dispatch_group_enter(group);
            [self getTemperatureHistorySuccess:^(NSArray<TemperatureSetDTO *> *sets) {
                self.temperatureSets = sets;
                dispatch_group_leave(group);
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                dispatch_group_leave(group);
            }];

            dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                [self showLoading:NO];
                [self updateChartWithVibrationHistory:self.vibrationPoints temperatureSets:self.temperatureSets];
            });
```

There are 2 enters, and 2 exits (on each of the closures, it is only possible to either be successful or failed, so only one of the 2 happen)

So why is my code crashing like this? How can I trouble shoot this?

[image]

The only other thing that comes to mind, is that multiple instances of this object do get used at the same time. Is it possible that the same group is being used by those different instances? Would there be a way to make sure the group itself is unique between those instances? Otherwise I can't think of why this is happening.

PS: I added swift tag as well to get more attention into the question as the same problem could happen no matter the language

**EDIT 1**

Adding missing methods based on comment received:

This is `getTemperatureHistorySuccess` which is the one that crashed

```
-(void)getTemperatureHistorySuccess:(void (^)(NSArray<TemperatureSetDTO*> *sets))success
                            failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure{
    NSMutableArray *sets = [NSMutableArray new];
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (TemperatureSummaryNew *sensor in self.regionPCA.temperatureSensors) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [TemperatureSensorsService getHistory:sensor.temperatureSensorID startDate:self.startDate stopDate:self.stopDate interval:self.currentInterval success:^(NSArray<TemperaturePointDTO *> *result) {
            TemperatureSetDTO *set = [TemperatureSetDTO new];
            set.points = result;
            [sets addObject:set];
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        success(sets);
    });
}
```

and here is the `getHistory` that gets called in the loop:

```
+ (void) getHistory:(int)sensorID
          startDate:(NSDate*)startDate
           stopDate:(NSDate*)stopDate
           interval:(HistoryInterval)interval
            success:(void (^)(NSArray<TemperaturePointDTO*>* result))success
            failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure{
    ApiManager *api = [ApiManager sharedManager];

    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"TemperatureSensorID" : [Converter toDictionaryValueFromInt:sensorID],
                             @"StartDate" : [Converter toDictionaryValueGMTFromDate:startDate],
                             @"StopDate" : [Converter toDictionaryValueGMTFromDate:stopDate],
                             @"Interval" : [Converter toDictionaryValueFromHistoryInterval:interval]};
    [api POST:kApiTemperatureSensorsGetHistory parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if (success) {
            NSArray*  res = [Converter fromDictionaryValueToTemperaturePointDTOArray:responseObject];
            success(res);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Here is `getVibrationHistorySuccess`

```
-(void)getVibrationHistorySuccess:(void (^)(NSArray<VibrationPointDTO *> *vibrationPoints))success
          failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure{
    __block NSArray<VibrationPointDTO *> *points;
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self getDistanceHistorySuccess:^{
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [VibrationSensorsService getHistory:self.regionPCA.regionID startDate:self.startDate stopDate:self.stopDate interval:self.currentInterval success:^(NSArray<VibrationPointDTO *> *result) {
        points = result;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
        failure(error);
    }];
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        success(points);
    });
}
```

`VibrationSensorsService getHistory` is exactly the same as the previous one, but pointing to a different endpoint

Comment: You haven't shown us the source code to `getVibrationHistorySuccess:failure:` or `getTemperatureHistorySuccess:failure:`, so we have no evidence that they only call one of the blocks and that they only call a block once. Your crash is evidence that one of them *does* call out more than once.

Comment: Hey @robmayoff I just added the source code for those other methods. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the last part of `getVibrationHistorySuccess:failure:`, copied from your question:

> ```
> [VibrationSensorsService getHistory:self.regionPCA.regionID startDate:self.startDate stopDate:self.stopDate interval:self.currentInterval success:^(NSArray<VibrationPointDTO *> *result) {
>     points = result;
>     dispatch_group_leave(group);
> } failure:^(NSError *error) {
>     dispatch_group_leave(group);
>     failure(error);
> }];
> dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
>     success(points);
> });
> ```

This code **always** calls `success(points)`. In addition, it **sometimes** calls `failure(error)`. That means both the `success` and `failure` blocks may be executed.

Comment: I was about to thank you in the comments because actually making me write down those methods made me find this exact problem myself. Glad you made an actual answer for it because I was going to answer it myself and you definitely deserved the points. Thank you!